# How to do a subquery within a select statement

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(SELECT pid
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state not like 'idle%'
AND query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%'
AND age(clock_timestamp(), query_start) > interval '600 minutes');
```

The code fails

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
  Position: 26
```

I just want to stop some backend processes that are stuck, and do it programmitcally. I have this in a PLPGSQL procedure.

Comment: Enclose inner SELECT in `()`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the outer select:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state not like 'idle%'
AND query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%'
AND age(clock_timestamp(), query_start) > interval '600 minutes';
```

Note that within a PL/pgSQL procedure you will need to use `perform` instead of SELECT. See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) for details